# GKE Socket.IO disconnects after 30s timeout

Tags: socket.io, google-kubernetes-engine, load-balancing, kubernetes-ingress

I have a GKE cluster with Ingress and node.js app running through a ClusterIP service. The connection to socket.io is successfull, however it auto disconnects after 30s timeout.

I have read this: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-features#timeout

And I created a BackendConfig yaml manifest changed it to something bigger:

```
apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1
kind: BackendConfig
metadata:
  name: my-backendconfig
spec:
  timeoutSec: 60
```

Then I tried to add annotations in the Ingress:

```
cloud.google.com/backend-config: '{"default": "my-backendconfig"}'
```

It didn't work. Then I removed it from the Ingress and tried to add the same annotation in the node.js app ClusterIp service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: api-srv
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/backend-config: '{"default": "my-backendconfig"}'
spec:
  selector:
    app: api
  ports:
    - name: api
      protocol: TCP
      port: 3003
      targetPort: 3003
```

However socket.io connection is still getting auto-disconnect after 30s.

This is the GKE version: 1.21.6-gke.1500

Comment: Which `Ingress` are you using, `GCP` or `Nginx`? Is it possible to provide your `ingress` yaml (without private information) and other configuration YAMLs? Could you provide steps to replicate this behavior? Can you share some logs?

Comment: @PjoterS hey, I have fixed this, see my answer, hope I helped.

Answer (score 1):

I had to put this in the ClusterIP service and not in the Ingress. Then I had to restart the server (delete and apply again) and it works. No disconnections for the Socket.IO.